# Multiple VS 2017 Projects in one Docker Container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-for-windows

I am using VS 2017 15.6.4 which is the latest version. I have a single solution that has three web projects in it:

Solution:

- Web Project 1
- Web Project 2
- Web Project 3

I would like to add Docker support so that all the web projects end up in a single container running IIS with the following IIS site structure:

Root Site (Web Project 1)

- Admin Virtual Application (Web Project 2)
- Campaign Virtual Application (Web Project 3)

Is there a way to accomplish this in Visual Studio 2017? When I add Docker support it seems to be on a project by project basis. I can run each project in its own container with no issues. Will I be forced to do this outside of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar question and found the following helpful. Make sure you have Docker CE installed on your machine, along with VS2017 with Docker support. In VS2017, when you do "Add->Docker Support", it should automatically include the docker-compose.yml file at the root of your solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/multi-container-applications-docker-compose#step4_define_svcs_in_docker_compose_yml

There is also a sample application posted on github, linked below. Note that this follows .Net Core v2.1. I'm assuming you are using .net core and if so, note that v2.0 is end of life later this year so you should consider moving to v2.1

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

The github project above also has links to some free books talking more on docker and .net core. They helped me out a lot!